# Try different functions until there is no exception, then continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I have 3 steps in my project. The first and last never change. The 2nd needs to loop through multiple functions until there is no exception, and then move on to the 3rd.

So basically:

```
func1()
func2a() #if exception move to func2b(), if no exception move to func3()
func2b() #if exception move to func2c(), if no exception move to func3()
func2c() #if exception move back to func2a(), if no exception move to func3()
func3() #if executes, break
```

I've tried multiple `try/except` with no luck

Comment: There is nothing passed to the functions.  They are all independent.  Edited to make more sense

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to achieve can be elegantly accomplished by packing the functions to a list. Then you iterate on the list and execute as long as there is an exception. To get the cyclic effect (go back to `2a` from `2c`) you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
from itertools import cycle

funcs = [func2a, func2b, func2c, ...]

func1()
for func in cycle(funcs):
    try:
        func()
    except:
        continue
    else:
        break
func3()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you:

```
f1()
while True:
        try:
            fa()
            break
        except:
            try:
                fb()
                break
            except:
                try:
                    fc()
                    break
                except:
                    pass
            
f3()
```

Or you can use a variable like this:

```
func1()
x = 'a'
while True:
    if x == 'a':
        try:
            func2a()
            break
        except:
            x = 'b'
    elif x == 'b':
        try:
            func2b()
            break
        except:
            x = 'c'
    else:
        try:
            func2c()
            break
        except:
            x = 'a'           
func3()
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as well.  I did come to a solution I believe that I'll put below